# Can you help me identify this LEGO Star Wars ship?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Which ship and LEGO model number is this?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is from

[75155-1: Rebel U-wing Fighter](https://brickset.com/sets/75155-1/Rebel-U-wing-Fighter)
[image]

Keypart : [6180pb115L : Tile, Modified 4 x 6 with Studs on Edges with 5 Worn Blue Rectangles and Black Lines on White Background Pattern Model Left Side (Sticker) - Set 75155](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6180pb115L#T=C&C=1)